# Solve OD-matrix for distance, add travel time to outputs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.5

I have an ArcGIS bike network with two kinds of streets. The first are just regular streets, where a biker has a speed of 6km/h. The second type are dedicated bike lanes where a biker has a speed of 10km/h.

Now i would like to solve a closest facility problem with the network analyst. I would like to solve for closest distance, but I also would like to know the travel time that belongs to this closest distance.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
In the accumulation tab, you can add other impedances to columns of the OD-matrix